# iOS, bluetooth scanner blocks wifi

Tags: ios, bluetooth, wifi

I have a strange problem with my app. On my iPhone 7 with iOS 10.1 or 10.2(Beta) it seems like the Bluetooth scanner seems to block the internet connection through wifi. Meaning when I'm in airplane mode and have Bluetooth activated, my app has no internet access. When I turn Bluetooth off, the internet through wifi works fine.
With other apps (also using Bluetooth) I do not experience this issue. No even stranger. Other Phones using iOS 9 or 10 do not have that issue with my app.
I tried restarting the phone, resetting network settings. Reinstalling the app. Nothing helped.

Anybody experiencing similar issues?

Comment: "...when i´m in airplane mode and have bluetooth activated my app has no internet access...": when in airplane mode, there is no internet connection. Maybe I misunderstood.

Comment: when in airplane mode and wifi activated the app should have interne access. Just not thru the mobile data.

Comment: I was not aware you can re-activate WIFI in Airplane mode. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I have met the similar situation while we tested an app using Bluetooth connection on Dec 19 in 2016.

`Device:iPhone 6/A1586/Hong Kong
OS:iOS 10.2`

The app using Bluetooth A2DP and BLE connection.When we update the iPhone 6 to iOS 10.2.

> *1.We found that we can not get the Bluetooth scanning list in Bluetooth Settings.*
>   *Note:we have Wi-Fi and 4G (China Mobile) connection.*
>
> *2.When we turn off Wi-Fi connection,we still can not get the Bluetooth scanning list in Bluetooth Settings.*
>
> *3.When we turn on Airplane mode,It means that we turn off Wi-Fi connection and 4G connection,and then we got the the Bluetooth scanning list in Bluetooth Settings!*
>
> *4.BLE scanning list is the same situation!*

**It means the that the Wi-Fi and 4G connection disturbed Bluetooth scanning!**

And now I try to update my iPhone 6S to iOS 10.2 that has already been downloaded in my iPhone, I have got this information,and the same situation happened in other 2 iPhone 6 devices.

[image]

Maybe this is a bug in iOS 10.2,and the official try to fix it and doesn't let us update to iOS 10.2 right now!

Comment: I noticed the same with the update. Actually for me it´s gone since 10.2.

Comment: What's version of your iOS you had met this problem?

Comment: It was the latest Beta before the final 10.2